# Connect to server protected with SSL from Android application

Tags: android, ssl, okhttp

I am junior android developer and created app, all worked good, but when we added SSL protection to site problems started. I added key.pem to assets folder and tryed use this [example](https://github.com/mklimek/ssl-utils-android)  but it did not work out. Please help, how I can fix this?

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gogo);

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    SSLContext sslContext = SslUtils.getSslContextForCertificateFile("cert.pem");
    client.setSslSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());

    HttpUrl.Builder urlBuilder = HttpUrl.parse("https://mysite/API/login.php").newBuilder();
    urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("username", "xxxxxx");
    urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("appkey", "xxxxxxx");
    String url = urlBuilder.build().toString();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(String.valueOf(urlBuilder))
            .build();


    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
            if (!response.isSuccessful()){
                throw new IOException("Unexpected code"+ response);
            }
        }
    });




}
```

and this my stack

`W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:333)
W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connectTls(Connection.java:235)
W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connectSocket(Connection.java:199)
W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:172)
W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:367)
W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:128)
W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:328)
W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:245)
W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:267)
W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:224)
W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:195)
W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.access$100(Call.java:34)
W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$AsyncCall.execute(Call.java:162)
W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:33)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
W/System.err: Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:225)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:115)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:571)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:329)
W/System.err:   ... 16 more
W/System.err: Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.`

Comment: If everything is set up correctly, you don't need to do anything special. Just replace the http URL by an https one.

Comment: can you please add the code where you actually send the request, and also show the actual problem you are having? (ie. the error message, stack trace, whatever)

Comment: Which error message do you get and which certificate does the server use (is it a valid trusted certificate)?

Comment: follow this link hope so you will get some solution https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html

Comment: Which are the exact effects of "does not work" ?

Comment: Does your site send the proper certificates during the handshake? Check using a scanner such as SSL Labs to ensure there are no chain issues reported.

Answer (score 0):

**Check this method to get httpClient:**

```
public static OkHttpClient getHttpClientForFile() {
        ConnectionSpec spec = new ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS)
                .tlsVersions(TlsVersion.TLS_1_0)
                .cipherSuites(
                        CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                        CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                        CipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                        CipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
                        CipherSuite.TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
                        CipherSuite.TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA)
                .build();
        return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .writeTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .readTimeout(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .connectionSpecs(Collections.singletonList(spec))
                .protocols(Arrays.asList(Protocol.HTTP_1_1))
                .build();
    }
```

for more visit [here](https://lalitjadav007.blogspot.in/2017/03/ssl-handshake-error-on-android.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use retrofit and okhttp instead of this. And u can change the http url to https and thats all. No need pem files